# Textchange event not working when jquery function is used

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using range slider of javascript in asp.net, i want to call code behind function for data binding so i have used on textchange event but evnt does not get fired when textchnged by jsfuction is there any other option to bind data when range slider value is changed.

Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <input id="myRange" type="range" min="1" max="10" value="1" class="slider" 
           onchange="abc()">
    <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
</div>
<script>
    var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
    var output = document.getElementById("demo");
    output.innerHTML = slider.value;
    slider.oninput = function() {

        output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
    var hiddenControl = '<%= inpHide.ClientID %>';
    document.getElementById(inpHide).value = output;

    function abc() {
        var hdnvalue = document.getElementById("demo");
        document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value = hdnvalue.innerText;
    }
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" CausesValidation="true" 
   OnTextChanged="TextBox2_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: `TextBox2_TextChanged` ?? I don't see that function declared anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to force the event call from javacript function like this:-

```
function abc()
 {
      var hdnvalue = document.getElementById("demo");   
      document.getElementById('<%=TextBox2.ClientID%>').value = hdnvalue.innerText;
      __doPostBack('TextBox2','TextChanged');
 }
```

You can also set the focus and remove it programmatically but that will be a bit lengthy approach.

Comment: @Tejashri - You're welcome. At SO, you can just accept\ upvote the answer to thank user, see how:- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Can i do  postback only textbox because i don't want range slider value to get refresh or please suggest any other solution because i am getting correct output on slider change but slider value gets reset

Comment: @Tejashri - That's how ASP.NET works, it post the whole form back to server. So either do it using AJAX or use some _State Management_ technique to preserve sliders value. Do some reading on State Management.